# how to solve Prototype Pollution lodash after npm audit fix requires manual review

Tags: node.js, lodash

when I do npm audit it gives me this link saying that the I have to update lodash in my NODEJS application https://www.npmjs.com/advisories/782 but I tried npm install lodash@latest --save and it didn't it still gives me the same vunerabilities, I think thats why its not loading the localhost

Answer (score 0):

Sounds silly but many times the fix can be the simplest, most obvious:

```
$ rm -rf node_modules/
$ npm install
$ npm audit
```

As reported here (https://thehackernews.com/2019/07/lodash-prototype-pollution.html), there were patches made in old pull requests that ended up getting updated.  I'm not certain, but perhaps you ran `npm audit fix` *before* those patches got merged.

I just fixed mine a short while ago with a simple `npm audit fix`.